# popToRootViewController then pushViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to write a piece of code that will pop to the root view controller, then will push another view controller, I have this so far:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Posts") as! PostsController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

The navigation controller is going to the root view controller, but its not pushing the other view controller, I get this is my console log:

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is
>   discouraged

Is what I am trying to do not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
if let navCont = navigationController {
    var controllers = navCont.viewControllers
    controllers.removeLast()
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Posts") as! PostsController
    controllers.append(viewController)
    navCont.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This works, but is there away instead of removeLast() or removeAll() can I remove all of them except the first one?

Comment: Never mind, I just removed them all, then appended two view controllers and that seems to work well, unless you have another suggestion.